# Uncaught Reference Error : <<some value >> not defined Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know this issue is faced by many pupil. I am not sure what's issue in the code. Although i properly ordered my script tag i got the following issue.

I need to send a value from one PHP file to other PHP. Which inturn used in js. Below is the code.

delete1.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#container').load('delete2.php?os=' + 'myos');
        });
    </script>

    <title>Cognizant's Asset Tracker</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id = "container" style = "min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

delete2.php

```
<?php
 $test = $_GET['os'];
 echo $test;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jstest = <?php echo $test; ?>;
    console.log(jstest);
});
</script>
```

When i executed i got the below output.
[image]

I am using bootstrap 3.3.6.
Appreciate your support.

Comment: What do you expect?! You literally write `var jstest = myos;` in the script. What should that variable `myos` contain? You have not defined it anywhere in that script.

Comment: This is not the actual code. Its replica of my issue. Depending on the variable i sent from delete1.php to delete2.php i should do respective functionality. In my actual code i will send graphType bar or pie. if its bar then i should display bar graph else pie graph. but as a first step i couldnt able to send the variable.

Comment: So let me get this straight: User loads delete1.php. delete1.php contains some variable `myos`. You load delete2.php via ajax. Now you expect the contents of the variable `myos` in delete1.php to be accessible in the javascript of delete2.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to quote the printed string or it gets printed as  a variable name and that undefined variable is throwing the error shown

```
var jstest = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
```